# JavaScript Square Bracket as Variable Value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, csrf

I have a need to pass the variable value as a name in the below function using [tokenName] for CSRF purposes. It works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE11.

The error I get is: **Expected identifier, string or number** on the [tokenName] line.

Thoughts?

```
    $('#container').on('click','#delete',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this),
            form = button.closest('form'),
            id = button.attr('data-id'),
            verify = button.attr('data-verify'),
            tokenName = form.find('input[name=token_name]').val(),
            tokenHash = form.find('input[name=' + tokenName + ']').val();

        // delete user via ajax
        $.post(form.attr('action'), {
                "id" : id,
                "object" : verify,
                [tokenName] : tokenHash
            }, function(data) {

            // do stuff


        }, "json");

    });
```

Comment: Don't use IE. . .

Comment: I don't have a choice what browsers people use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always fall back to older syntax:

```
  var options = {
      "id" : id,
      "object" : verify,
  };

  options[tokenName] = tokenHash;

  $.post(form.attr('action'), options, function(data) {
      //...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using variable as a key in a Javascript object literal is an ES6 Feature

`[tokenName] : tokenHash` this feature is not supported by IE 11

#### Click [here](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to see ES Compatability Tables for various js engines